# Using no-ip to make android public

Tags: android, webserver, ip

I would like to make my android phone publicly available, i am connected to my wifi access point now i have created a host on no-ip and i want to know how to forward the traffic from the host to my android on port 8080 in android.Please help me.

Comment: ok but please help me. i will not do this again :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to forward the port 8080 to your phones local IP in the Router-Menu.
When your phone is connected via 3G to the internet, most Providers will block incoming requests to your phone.

Comment: then if i type the host in any browser will it work.

Comment: and if i do not use any router than is there any method ..

Comment: if your host is directly connected to the internet, you need some kind of Software Router. You can use VirtualBox and ipfire as Router.configure your network interfaces in bridged mode.Or try to use any other Software Router.

Comment: i think u did not understand the quest.. i created a host on no-ip from my phone so the ip of my phone and host will be same now is there any method that if i type the host:port in browser will it show up. and if im not connected to the router just my phone with 3g support please help

Comment: So maybe your provider will block incoming requests to your phone. I can only access my phone when i am connected via wifi and port forward from my Router to my phones wifi IP. I cannot access same port when connected via 3g and using phones public IP.

Comment: so you are saying that if you are connected to wifi and in router's config page you forward the traffic comming from host to your device ip isn't